# Unable to get each cell Value in Telerik RadGrid BatchEdit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have Telerik RadGrid with BatchEditMode,

my requirement is on button click get all the values of the cells (entered during batch edit mode), but i am unable to get those values.
My Main Target is to pass whole RadGrid as a Datatable to Database Procedure.
Here is my Telerik RadGrid Code.

```
enter code here
     <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
            CellSpacing="0" GridLines="Both"
            OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" AllowPaging="false"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            onneeddatasource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
            >
            <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="true">
                <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" CellSelectionMode="MultiColumn" />
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
                <Resizing AllowColumnResize="true" AllowResizeToFit="true" />

                <ClientEvents OnBatchEditGetCellValue="BatchEditGetCellValue"   OnCellSelected="cellSelected"  OnRowCreated="RowCreated" 
                    OnBatchEditOpening="BatchEditOpening"
                     />
            </ClientSettings>

            <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Bottom" Width="100%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                FilterItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="COLUMN1"
                HorizontalAlign="Justify" EditMode="Batch" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

                <BatchEditingSettings EditType="Cell" SaveAllHierarchyLevels="true"  />

            </SortExpressions>--%>

                <Columns>




                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CFIT_ID" HeaderText="Cashflow" SortExpression="ProductName"
                        UniqueName="CFIT_ID" Display="false">
                        <ColumnValidationSettings EnableRequiredFieldValidation="true">
                            <RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" Text="*This field is required" Display="Dynamic">
                            </RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </ColumnValidationSettings>
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>



                     <telerik:GridNumericColumn DataField="COLUMN1" HeaderStyle-Width="83px" HeaderText="COLUMN1" 
                        SortExpression="COLUMN1" UniqueName="COLUMN1">
                    </telerik:GridNumericColumn>






                </Columns>

            </MasterTableView>

        </telerik:RadGrid>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"  Text="Submit"/>

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Trying to Get Value of each Numeric Cell Value using this code.

foreach (GridEditableItem item in RadGrid1.Items)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();

```
            RadNumericTextBox DNumericTextBox = (RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetBatchColumnEditor("COLUMN1") as GridNumericColumnEditor).NumericTextBox;
            dr["COLUMN1"] = item["COLUMN1"].Text.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this link first for demos and understanding [Grid - Batch Editing](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/batch-editing/defaultcs.aspx)

I am using `BatchEditingSettings EditType="Row"`. Following is the code for BatchEditing.

```
foreach (GridBatchEditingCommand command in e.Commands)
{
    Hashtable insValues = command.NewValues;

    #region insert new

    if (command.Type == GridBatchEditingCommandType.Insert)
    {
        string name = insValues["name"].ToString();
    }

    #endregion

    #region update existing

    if (command.Type == GridBatchEditingCommandType.Update)
    {
        string name = insValues["name"].ToString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Yes i have already searched it but issue is, demo is using commanditem  Save Changes event in which they will get the edited rows but i wanted to get edited rows in my custom event...